# My app freezes and I don't know what's wrong

Tags: objective-c, freeze

So, my app works perfectly except that it freezes after a while of using it in the simulator. Any ideas?

The following error occurs:

```
App Game[6352:60b] *** Assertion failure in -[UIWindowController transition:fromViewController:toViewController:target:didEndSelector:animation:], /SourceCache/UIKit/UIKit-2935.137/UIWindowController.m:223
2014-04-18 11:32:43.237 App Game[6352:60b] *** WebKit discarded an uncaught exception in the webView:didFinishLoadForFrame: delegate: <NSInternalInconsistencyException> Attempting to begin a modal transition from <ViewController: 0x15f625180> to <GADWebAppViewController: 0x15f53e5d0> while a transition is already in progress. Wait for viewDidAppear/viewDidDisappear to know the current transition has completed
2014-04-18 11:32:49.603 App Game[6352:60b] Warning: Attempt to present <Game: 0x15f659030> on <ViewController: 0x15f625180> while a presentation is in progress!
```

Comment: You are trying to open a modalVC in the middle of transitioning to another VC. You cannot do this at the same time. You have to wait with any UI things until the VC you are currently transitioning to is fully visible/appeared (or invisible/disappeared). You are too hasty trying to present your modalVC

Comment: Seeing error's, I could get that you are trying to present a view in middle of a view which is in progress. So you need to debug and check for view presenting.

Comment: are you using the deprecated method presentModalViewController:animated:?

Comment: Try setting the exception breakpoint in the debugger. That should take you to the offending line of code when the problem occurs.

Comment: Without seeing some code, best guess is that either your code is trying to present the same modal view controller more than once at the same time, or that you are trying to present it while a view controller transition is in process. Try adding log statements in relevant `viewWillAppear`, `viewDidAppear`, `viewWillDisappear`, and `viewWillDisappear`, and `presentModalViewController`. The modal must not be presented between the calls of `viewWillAppear` and `viewDidAppear` of a VC.

Comment: what i'm basically trying to do is to make an interstitial gad. and no i'm not @vin

Comment: How do you suggest I should do? Thank you for your answer. @TotumusMaximus

Comment: @SimonPersson I suggest you show us how you coded the way you present all involved UIViewControllers, popups, modalviewcontrollers during this error. Your answer lies in-between these presentations. What I would like to see/read is what specific manipulations you are attempting just before and during the error.

Comment: ViewController.h: http://i.gyazo.com/2b6b275fca65a7adc1a736990421ea54.png

ViewController.m: http://i.gyazo.com/044f4c4096ad6ec9a359687101cc6371.png and http://i.gyazo.com/c44f844fa8ecda0ced058f14a672a9a6.png @TotumusMaximus

Comment: @SimonPersson Ok, the problem is this. Your loading of the ad is done faster then it took to get your view controller in screen. This caused the app to be confused on what to present on screen and caused a crash. Don't try to load/present this stuff from the viewDidLoad. But rather wait until the viewController did the viewDidAppear: function (so maybe place the loadRequest functions here?). Also when your interstitialDidReceiveAd: function is called you don't check if you already have something presented on your screen. You can never present 2 things like this.

Comment: The check in the interstitialDidReceiveAd: could be enough to fix this. But check into the placement of the loadRequest to be sure. Your problem should be solved with this.

Comment: I see. It seems like alot of things for me to handle. I don't understand English very well, I'm using Google Translate. But what you're saying is that I should replace some lines of code? Or add. Sorry, I don't understand. Thank you for your help @TotumusMaximus

Comment: 'interstitialDidReceiveAd:' in here, add an 'if-statement' to see if a 'ViewController' is already presented. If one is already presented, then do not present it. 'viewDidLoad', do not try to present something from here, the 'viewController' is not fully in screen yet. You will have to move the methods that try to present any other 'view'/'viewController' from the 'viewDidLoad' to the 'viewDidAppear'. This will prevent any crash from happening by trying to present multiple screens at the same time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just dealt with this problem. I was using the SimpleAuth to authenticate Instagram for an app, and found out that I was calling the SimpleAuth authorize method twice. The second call was causing this error by trying to present it's own modal before the first call had dismissed it's own.